# iOS 11.2 beta released, but not a corresponding Xcode beta

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9.1, xcode9.2, ios11.2

I've just installed iOS 11.2 Beta and downloaded the latest Xcode (which is 9.1 - beta 2. 9B46).

But when I try to run the app on the device it says it doesn't have the necessary support files.

So how am I supposed to develop with 11.2 beta if there's no corresponding Xcode yet?

Comment: I have reached out to the Apple Feedback program in regards to this already. I will let you know as soon as I hear back.

Comment: The release notes for iOS 11.2 beta state it requires Xcode 9.2 but Apple hasn't posted Xcode 9.2 yet. Looks like a screwup. Give them time (a day?) to fix it.

Comment: and Apple released xcode 9.2!

Comment: I got the same, very angry at apple to not have made sure that we can run curent Xcode on iOS 13.2 deice if Xcode 11.2 was not released yet.

Answer (score 3):

Well you have several options for now:

- Develop using the simulators while waiting for the Xcode beta to show up
- Revert back to a non-beta version of iOS (back up your phone!) and use previous versions of Xcode

My guess is the newest Xcode beta will show up either tomorrow or Wednesday so you won’t have to wait too long. I’m in the same boat.

Comment: Same problem here. As of 7:24 am CDT, no sign of an Xcode update.

Comment: @BillNorman Apple usually releases software and such at 1 PM EST so my guess is nothing until then

Comment: We have 3 December, a week after 11.2 was released for PRODUCTION, and there is no corresponding xcode yet;(

Answer (score 2):

As a temporal solution, you could download Xcode beta 9.2b2 and use device support from that Xcode.

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.2\ \(15C5097c\) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.2\ \(15C5097c\)
```

after that restart Xcode and replug device

Comment: For me I used the following and then restarted Xcode, then re-plugged in the iPad: `sudo ln -s '/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.2 (15C5097c)' '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.2 (15C114)'`

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion in regards to this on the Apple Developer Forums. As soon as it is resolved I'm sure this post will be updated.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/90859

Currently the only option is to use simulators or revert your iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 9.2 is now available for download via App Store or directly at: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.2/Xcode_9.2.xip (may require login)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9.1 and Xcode 9.2 beta are now available for download at https://developer.apple.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the latest version of `Xcode-beta.app` and use a bash shell script https://gist.github.com/hintoz/e8d60a04890bd864b5a39574c0ee0729 
to avoid creating links manually